# Updating WCF is not working while deployment on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

My Issue is not new , In fact many of my pals suffers from it

Coming to the point , Issue is while updating WCF.

**What is working :**

The code is working fine at locals

**What is not working**

What I did to do now ?

1. Do I need to remove all the waste code from IIS ?
2. Do I need to delete all the websites from IIS that are using same WCF
3. Do I need to delete OBJ and Bin Folder at locals and again need to try with Rebuild solution and then publish the project .

How can I make previous WCF services to release the port so that new updated one can use it.

**Every Single word of help should be appreciable**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you updated your service reference before publishing the services. Steps : Project -> Service References->  Right Click on Your Service Name -> Select Update Service Reference.

Comment: Do I need to did it everytime When I update my service ?

Comment: Where I can found this service reference option

Comment: Yah ofcourse   you need to do that every time when you make changes in you WCF code.

Comment: @LaxmanGite may I have your number please , I stucked on this minor issue , it will be very helpfull if you can guide me

Comment: @LaxmanGite PLease have a look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512029/get-response-from-the-asp-net-webservice-method-and-use-it-in-website?noredirect=1#comment77985154_45512029

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you did not update your service reference.

You need to update service when you make changes in your WCF service file.
After update the service you need to publish the code then and the it will work.

**Here is the snap for update services :**

[image]

Comment: this folder is inside the project or wcf

actualy I have one project and having 2 referenced wcfs, while uploading the code , I published the code . is that enough or do we need to do extra work to move WCF to the live server

Comment: Where you are accessing the wcf service in that project you will get the service reference.

Comment: yah there you will get this reference

Comment: Do I need to delete all unused and old code from IIS that is using this WCF earlier

Comment: Yes but do not need to delete webConfig file on server rest all folder and file you need to replace with latest publish code.

Comment: Okay sure , I am trying to get the access right now from client , If Got it i Will ping u ,

Comment: have you faced this bug before ?

Comment: Its not a bug, you haven't followed right steps for deployment.

Comment: Hoping the same bro ,